# What does OP stand for from salesforce's TransmogrifAI?

Tags: salesforce, transmogrifai

What does Op stand for from salesforce's TransmogrifAI? such as OpApp, OpWorkflow, etc.

https://github.com/salesforce/TransmogrifAI/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/salesforce/op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code name for the project before it was released was "Optimus Prime" thus the *OP* abbreviation.